# Best pracice to initialize a web application in oop (no framework)

Tags: php, initialization

I'm writing a web application and I would like to know how to initialize all constant (such as db connection data, directories etc), classes and so on.

I read about bootstrap file but I'm not sure I understand the technique ( more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774105/htaccess-and-bootstrap-file).

Comment: I know what you say in your title, but I think the very best practice is to use a framework. If you are discarding it to be too complicated, Yii is a powerful framework easy to learn. If you are discarding it to be dealing with some old PHP version, CakePHP 1.3 accept PHP 4. I wanted to tell you just in case you are discarding it for some of these reasons.

Comment: I'm discarding frameworks only because my web site is hosted in a shared hosting service and i doesn't allow any framework.

Comment: Hey @Marco. I have used a lot of times a framework in shared hostings. You only have to check it accomplishes minimum requirements. Usually this is very easy to know, for example Yii and Symfony, and surely the others, comes with a script you can upload to the server and it will tell you if the server is enough or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more specific case would be better. In this case, your question on settings, there are different approaches. Generally a config file is most used in projects. That way it can easily be excluded from version control systems.

Bootstrap files are not the location to store settings.

So bootstrap load the config file and following to that the bootstrap initiates the system.

Generally a config file is the most accepted choice.

For paths there are different parts. You have in-app paths. Keep them in your code, your system should be able to find the right files. Might be done with a PHP Autoloader for example.

Then you have paths to resources like images, pdf files and other data. Keep that part strongly separated from your application. Preferably via a class which handles all those files. That way you are free to move them to another server, move them to Amazon for example when your project grows etc.

So don't try to hardcode paths and keep things separated.